# Using PDFBox but it doesn't modify the pdf, and I am having trouble modifying one PDF whereas another PDF works

Tags: java, kotlin, pdfbox

I am trying to modify the PDF using Java [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) using Kotlin, and what is happening that I am modifying a text from a PDF with another text.

It works for one of my pdf template but not another one.

This code is being called to replace one text to another text. Also there is another function where it takes a PDF, generates a new PDF where it replaces the text.

```
private fun replacePage(page: PDPage, page2Stream: PDPageContentStream) {
        var font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD

        val parser = PDFStreamParser(page)
        parser.parse()

        val tokens = parser.tokens
        for (tokenIndex in tokens.indices) {
            val token = tokens[tokenIndex]

            if (token !is Operator) {
                continue
            }

            when (token.name) {
                OperatorName.BEGIN_TEXT -> {
                    page2Stream.beginText()
                }
                OperatorName.MOVE_TEXT -> {
                    val x = (tokens[tokenIndex - 2] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    val y = (tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    page2Stream.newLineAtOffset(x, y)
                }
                OperatorName.SET_MATRIX -> {
                    val ary = COSArray()
                    ary.addAll((6 downTo 1).map {
                        tokens[tokenIndex - it] as COSNumber
                    })
                    page2Stream.setTextMatrix(Matrix(ary))
                }
                OperatorName.SET_FONT_AND_SIZE -> {
                    val fontNameObj = tokens[tokenIndex - 2] as COSName
                    val fontSizeObj = tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSNumber
                    font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD
                    val fontSize = fontSizeObj.floatValue()
                    page2Stream.setFont(font!!, fontSize)
                }
                OperatorName.SHOW_TEXT -> {
                    val previous = tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSString
                    val buffer = parsePdfString(font!!, previous)
                    val buffer2 = replacePdfText(buffer)
                    page2Stream.showText(buffer2)
                }
                OperatorName.SHOW_TEXT_ADJUSTED -> {
                    val previous = tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSArray
                    val buffer = previous.filterIsInstance<COSString>().joinToString("") { obj ->
                        parsePdfString(font!!, obj)
                    }

                    val buffer2 = replacePdfText(buffer)
                    page2Stream.showText(buffer2)
                }
                OperatorName.END_TEXT -> {
                    page2Stream.endText()
                }
                OperatorName.MOVE_TO -> {
                    val x = (tokens[tokenIndex - 2] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    val y = (tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    page2Stream.moveTo(x, y)

                }
                OperatorName.LINE_TO -> {
                    val x = (tokens[tokenIndex - 2] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    val y = (tokens[tokenIndex - 1] as COSNumber).floatValue()
                    page2Stream.lineTo(x, y)
                }
                OperatorName.STROKE_PATH -> {
                    page2Stream.stroke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you don't show *how* you "modify the PDF", what do you expect us to say? Allow me to remark, though, that there is a lot of "example code" out there that only works under benign circumstances.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F

Comment: I modified it and put the code

Comment: First of all, your code seems to process only a subset of the pdf operators and completely drops the others. This can substantially change the apostate of the page. Also it applies `replacePdfText` directly to the text pieces drawn for each instruction. This may take from complete lines to single glyphs. By the way, throwing away the numeric parameters of `OperatorName.SHOW_TEXT_ADJUSTED` can substantially change the result.